# Need a AppRTCMobile run log?

Tags: ios, webrtc, apprtcdemo, apprtc

I trying to use webrtc ios, but I encounter some diffcult, I hope one running log of AppRTCMobile (ios). Can you help me.

Comment: If you have, please send to `janu.zhou@gamil.com` .   Thks.

Comment: Have you found it??

Comment: @RajatKothari  Yes. please ignore the issue. it's past tense.